# Is it possible to create a const object with Symbol keys?

Tags: ecmascript-6

e.g.

```
const AES_256_CBC = Symbol();

const encHeaders = {
   AES_256_CBC: "foo",
}
```

This of course doesn't work because the key is actually the literal string `"AES_256_CBC"`.

Normally you'd just set your properties after initializing the object to an empty hash,

```
var encHeaders = {};
encHeaders[AES_256_CBC] = "foo";
```

But I can't do this *and* have `encHeaders` be `const`, can I?

Comment: I think you're looking for `const encHeaders = Ojbect.freeze({[AES_256_CBC]: "foo"});`

Answer (score 3):

> But I can't do this and have `encHeaders` be `const`, can I?

Yes you can. `const` has no impact on the value, it only affects the binding itself. That is, you cannot *assign* a new value to `encHeaders` but you can certainly mutate the value itself (if it's mutable).

Comment: Symbol properties don't show up in `console.log` do they? When I tried it, it looked like it wasn't being added.

Comment: There is no spec for `console.log`, so the answer would be: depends on the environment.

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. You can do it with square brackets:

```
const AES_256_CBC = Symbol();

const encHeaders = Object.freeze({
   [AES_256_CBC]: "foo",
});

console.log(encHeaders[AES_256_CBC]); // foo
```

The square bracket notation was also [added in ES6](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer).

**Update:** Amended to include [Bergi's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33511798/is-it-possible-to-create-a-const-object-with-symbol-keys/33512256?noredirect=1#comment54810153_33511798)